# Cannot close ngb-datepicker with .close() (.close() is not a function)

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I am attempting to set up a ngb-datepicker to close on clicking outside of it. I am however receiving this error:

```
GamesComponent.html:9 ERROR TypeError: dp.close is not a function
at GamesComponent.push../src/web/apps/command-center/games/games.component.ts.GamesComponent.closeCalendar (games.component.ts:202)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (GamesComponent.html:12)
at handleEvent (core.js:10050)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11143)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:10846)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:7509)
at core.js:7953
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:1140)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3748)
```

The relevant html is below

```
<ng-template #popContent class="col-lg-3 align-items-center">
        <ngb-datepicker (select)="convertNgbDatetoDate($event)"
                        name="dp" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker"
                        (blur)="onInputBlur()"
                        (document:click)="closeCalendar($event, d)">
        </ngb-datepicker>
</ng-template>
```

and the ts

```
closeCalendar(event, dp) {

    console.log(dp)

    const path = event.path.map(p => p.localName);
    if ((!path.includes('ngb-datepicker') && !path.includes('ng- 
    container') && !path.includes('gns-sentient-dates') && 
    !path.includes('howser-input'))) {
        dp.close();
        this.onInputBlur();
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to what I am missing?

Comment: The `close()` only exists on `input[ngbDatepicker]` and NOT on `<ngb-datepicker>`. But closing on outside click is already fully implemented in ng-bootstrap from version 3.2.2.

Answer (score -1):

Closing ngb-datepicker with clicking outside is an open issue of [ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) since 2016. Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/783).

Possible workarounds:

**A)**

use view:

`(click)="d.toggle(); $event.stopPropagation();" (document:click)="d.close()"`

**or B)**

use component:

```
if(!this._eref.nativeElement.querySelector('ngb-datepicker').contains(event.target)
    && !this._eref.nativeElement.querySelector('.input-group-addon').contains(event.target)) {
    let self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
       self.dynamicId.close();
    },10);
}
```

**or C)**

use view:

```
<input style="background-color: white;" class="form-control" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" name="date" [(ngModel)]="date" ngbDatepicker #eToggle="ngbDatepicker" (click)="eToggle.toggle(); sToggle.close();$event.stopPropagation()" (document:click)="decideClosure($event, eToggle)" readonly>
```

and component:

```
decideClosure(event, datepicker) { const path = event.path.map(p => p.localName); if (!path.includes('ngb-datepicker')) { datepicker.close(); } }
```

Comment: I tried to implement A) I am still getting the same error:
GamesComponent.html:9 ERROR TypeError: jit_nodeValue_3(...).close is not a function

Comment: Can you create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (e.g. use [https://stackblitz.com/](https://stackblitz.com/)) so we can run your code and modify? Google for "stackblitz ng-bootstrap" to find a template to integrate your code.

Comment: There are so many interdependencies in this project in a word no I cant.

Comment: Try to break down your problem to the main components and dependencies you need to reproduce it. It will help you to find the error. Good luck

Comment: The mentioned issue is NOT open - it was fixed in ng-bootstrap 3.2.2